# MessageBox sometimes doesnt open when pressing edges of Button1

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

xaml codes are here;

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Click Me" Click="Button1_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C# codes are here;

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Thanks for click");
}
```

vb.net codes are here;

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Thanks for click")
End Sub
```

Run above codes and click **center of Button1** and see that MessageBox shows you *Thanks for click*

***My question is here:***

When you click **edges of Button1** you will see that **Button1** behaves *pressing effect* but the MessageBox doesnt open! (Actually sometimes opens sometimes not!)

So, why that MessageBox **sometimes** doesnt open when clicking **edges of Button1**?

Please note that I have tried **LayoutTransform** instead of **RenderTransform** but this problem still exists.

Comment: It's probably because once you scale it to 90% the mouse is no longer pressing the button if you are clicking on the bottom edge. Try changing the color instead of scaling.

Comment: Something like this keeps the size the same but shows that the button is down:
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon got the right reason why you cannot open the `MessageBox`. The scale of your button and then the hitting out of range is the right reason.

You should redefine your button style to let the button hittable everywhere.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <!-- This transparent background is important,
                     because it helps you to hit the button even when it is scaled to 0.9. -->
                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border x:Name="RootBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="RootBorder" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that we add a transparent `Border` outside so that the button can always be hit by the edge.